# 111 invalid type for key Pointer, expected *, but got string

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am saving a object I call action to Parse.com

and I am getting the following error:

```
111 invalid type for key bookPointer, expected *Book, but got string
```

The code I use is:

```
 action.set("bookPointer", "SPecEgZUhL");

 action.save(null, {
                success: function (data) {
                    // The object was saved successfully.
                    callback(true);
                },
                error: function (data,error) {
                    // The save failed.
                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    callback(false);
                }
            });
```

And my Book data looks like:

[image]

How do I get the pointer to my book, my *book in javascript?

Make sense to me that it should work fine with the objectId.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this work? `action.set("bookPointer", { __type: "Pointer", className: "Book", objectId: "SPecEgZUhL" });`

Comment: @Dogbert, yes that works! Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler/more strongly typed method would be:

```
// Assumes var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Book");
action.set("bookPointer", new Book({id: "SPecEgZUhL"}));
```

it's also not typically conventional to name columns after their type (e.g. "book" instead of "bookPointer")

Answer (score 7):

As I said in the comment on the question, you can specify a pointer using a JS object like this in your case:

```
{
  __type: "Pointer",
  className: "Book",
  objectId: "SPecEgZUhL"
}
```

Final code becomes:

```
action.set("bookPointer", { __type: "Pointer", className: "Book", objectId: "SPecEgZUhL" });
```

Found it on the examples given on this page - https://www.parse.com/docs/rest

Comment: I was running into similar problem:

{
code: 111
error: "invalid type for key createdBy, expected *_User, but got *User"
}

and I got it to work using your method. One small change is that the pre-defined class such as User need to be prefix with underscore

{"__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": "1234"}

Thanks!